# Multiple Object Editing: Affect all with proportional editing

Tags: edit-mode, selection-tools

Blender 2.8 allows to select and edit multiple objects at once ([see developer task here](https://developer.blender.org/T54641)).

When I do that, and I turn proportional editing on, only the object from which the faces I have selected is affected.

[image: Lower part not scaled]

Is there a way to turn affection on for all objects in edit mode?
It works if I select a single face from each object:

[image: works when faces from the other object are selected]